# EF Core add migration with two FK to the same entity Issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 2.0.3 as code first.

Here is my Project entity:

```
[Table("Project")]
public class ProjectEntity
{

    [Key]
    [Column("ProjectId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
    public virtual ClientEntity Client { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual ProjectEntity Parent { get; set; }

    public int MasterId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a FK to Project with `ParentId`
Then I changed the Project Model and make `MasterId` as FK:

```
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public virtual ProjectEntity Master { get; set; }
```

then I run the `add-migration` command, and here is the result:

```
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Project_Project_ParentId",
            table: "Project");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Project_ParentId",
            table: "Project");
```

First the migration remove the ParentId Fk, Why?

Second It's not added any Fk for MasterId?

any idea for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be tracked [EF Core self referencing not working if there are 2 foreign keys to self (Code first) #10123](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10123).

I could reproduce this issue when `ProjectEntity` configures more than two `FKs`.

I assume `MasterId` is nulllable. I suggest you try to modify your model like below:

```
[Table("Project")]
public class ProjectEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ProjectId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public virtual ProjectEntity Parent { get; set; }
    public int? MasterId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MasterId")]
    public virtual ProjectEntity Master { get; set; }
    public int? MasterId1 { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("MasterId1")]
    public virtual ProjectEntity Master1 { get; set; }

}
```

And then configure `ForeignKey` by `Fluent API` below:

```
    builder.Entity<ProjectEntity>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(e => e.Master1).WithOne()
              .HasForeignKey<ProjectEntity>(e => e.MasterId1)
              .HasConstraintName("ForeignKey_Project_Master1");
        entity.HasIndex(e => new { e.MasterId1 })
              .IsUnique(false);
    });
```